# Globally Access Variables for All Cucumber Steps from inside Hooks

Tags: ruby, cucumber

currently I am loading all YAML files inside Cucumber Hooks like this before- the intention is to ensure we dont code individually for loading YAML files.

```
@all_Yaml_Files = Dir.entries(@projectData_Path).select {|f| !File.directory? f};
@all_Yaml_Files.each do |file_Name|
    file_Full_Path = @projectData_Path + '/' + file_Name
    instance_variable_set("@" + file_Name.split('.')[0], YAML.load_file(file_Full_Path))
end
```

However this code is inside a Before Cucumber Hook. So When the instance variables are loaded they are not available for next scenario. How can I make them run only once and then be available for all scenarios and all features - ie globally. Currently its loading everytime for a scenario.

```
Before do
....
end
```

Note: By doing above , we can directly access a YAML_FileName by @YAML_FileName variable without writing code. Thats my intention. Same happens with all excel files, json files etc etc. They are all called from inside Hooks.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: added the "quick" solution

#### Quick solution

You are using class variables (`@var`) now; these are subject to some Cucumber magic so they are cleaned out after each scenario, as you noticed. This makes them rather useful as well, giving you a "clean slate" while allowing you to transfer some state from one step to the next.

This *is* all just Ruby, so you can of course use global ruby variables (`$var`) instead. This still requires you to change your existing code.

If you want to keep your class variables `@var` and still have them to stick around, you could do hooks to save and restore them in globals, i.e.:

```
Around do |scenario, block|
  @var = $var
  begin
    block.call
  ensure
    $var = @var
  end
end
```

You'll want to make sure this hook is encountered early enough so it fires before any other hooks you might have.

I don't like to use globals in any language, so I try not to use either `@var` or `$var` in Cucumber. Instead, I prefer to do it the OOP way... hence:

#### "Clean" solution (PORO)

I use a singleton module for such things:

```
# support/000_cucu_globals.rb

class CucuGlobals
  include Singleton

  def initialize 
    @somevalue = 'hello world'
    ...
  end

  attr_reader :somevalue
end
```

Elsewhere:

```
puts CucuGlobals.instance.somevalue + "!"
```

Adjust/extend/get creative, as necessary. If you want to avoid typing so much, feel free to use a shorter class name (like `G` for global). You can also make your accessors class methods instead to even skip the `instance` in between. This is all just Ruby (not Cucumber) at this point, so there is not Cucumber magic involved anymore.

Hint: you want to load this module pretty early. I'm sure there is a good way to do that "cleanly", but I opted to just name it in such a way that is found first, by Cucumber (`000_...`).

Comment: 1. ok this seems nice  - but are they gonna get invoked everytime a sceanrio or feature is invoked - or is it Before All Suite sort of.

Comment: 2. I dont want my testing users to invoke a class before the instance variable name. for example now they use @Filename. Now they need to use SomeClassName.filename .. which adds to what we are doing now